# How do I legally quote one or two lines of lyrics in a novel I plan to publish?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, publishing

I've been thinking about publishing my novel on SmashWords and CreateSpace after having written it five years ago. However, in a paragraph, I quoted two lines of Lyrics, but didn't give the name of the song until I got to the Author Talks about <Name_of_Novel> heading.

This song is copyright 2012 by Hal Leonard Corporation. Testimony, by Stephen Schwartz. Would it be a good idea to keep the two lines of lyrics or remove them, but still keep the name of the song in the resources heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where and how you reproduce the lyrics in the book or how to point out the title of the song that contains the lyrics doesn't matter; simply printing two lines of the lyrics can be copyright infringement, [Fair Use (U.S. Copyright Office)](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html) not withstanding.

It's not a good idea to risk legal action against yourself or the need to defend yourself with a Fair Use argument. Ask for permission: [Request Permission to Reprint Lyrics in a Publication - Hal Leonard Online](https://www.halleonard.com/licensing/pre_lyric_request.jsp)